# React Mapping from a Seeds File

Tags: reactjs, mapping

Shown below in the screenshot is my Evolution Part 1 page done using HTML.

I am now trying to use react state https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines/client/components/EvolutionPart1.jsx to get classic ships displayed in boxes.

What I am doing is going from the Evolution Part 1 component to a new component called ClassicShips that picks up the ships by id order from my evo1 seeds file https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/tree/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines/seeds.

**My question is when I am doing the map as shown below how does it know that it should pick up the data from evo1 seeds file ?**

```
render()    { 
        return  (
            <div>
                <div className = "header">
                    <h1>Evolution of Cruise Ships</h1> 
                </div>
                <div className = "evoContainer">
                    {this.state.classicShips.map(ship =>    {
                    return  ( 
                            <ClassicShips key={ship.id} {...ship}/>
                    )  
                 }
              )}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/egDh9.png

Answer (score 0):

## Question

> how does it know that it should pick up the data from evo1 seeds file?

### If the question is about how the UI fetches and maps the response data

`getClassics` from `../api/api`

This does a GET request to fetch an array of ships.

The rest lies in `EvolutionPart1`. You have an empty array as initial `classicShips` state, so when the component mounts it can render an empty array. also when it mounts it calls `this.setUpClassics` which is a utility function to call the API function `getClassics` from above. When this fetch resolves and returns an array of ship data it `this.setState({ classicShips: res })` to update. This causes a component rerender and the new data is mapped.

EvolutionPart1

```
class EvolutionPart1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      classicShips: [], // <-- (1) initial empty array
    };
    this.setUpClassics = this.setUpClassics.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setUpClassics(); // <-- (2) fetch ship data
  }

  setUpClassics() {
    getClassics().then(res => {
      this.setState({
        classicShips: res // <-- (3) setState
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
        <div className="evoContainer">
          {this.state.classicShips.map(ship => { // <-- (4) map ship data to JSX
            return (
              <div className="evosShips" key={ship.id}>
                <h3>{ship.ship_name}</h3>
                <img src={ship.img} title={ship.img_title} />
                <p>Find out more on {ship.ship_name} , Click on image</p>
                <p>{ship.ship_name} Ship Horn</p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

### If the question is about how the server knows to load the `evo1` seeds file

- Gets config from [knexfile.js](https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines/knexfile.js)
- DB stood up and reads in seeds
- `dbclassics` [connects](https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines/server/db/dbclassics.js#L15) to `Evo1` table
- API [endpoint](https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines/server/routes/classics.js) serves up data

Comment: evoContainer that you show is being replaced by 

 <div className = "evoContainer">
                    {this.state.classicShips.map(ship =>    {
                    return  ( 
                            <ClassicShips key={ship.id} {...ship}/>)  })}

because props are passed to a new Classic Ships component.
Both of what you have told me is related to this question.
It seems like dbclassics is the one that picks out evo1 seeds table.
So it looks like I have my new mapping correct.
Some of the  code I have commented in api, like //return request.get(`/v1/classicships`) I need.

Comment: Hi Drew 

Just a quick question in https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines/server/db/dbclassics.js#L15 where I have return conn('Evo1').
If I was to have this for both my Evolution Part 1 and 2 pages, would it be acceptable to have return conn('Evo1', 'Evo2') 

I'm just wondering why it has the first letter 
capitalized with this, is that just the notation it likes ?

Comment: @RobWilkinson I'm guessing that is the name of the DB table that Knex instantiates from the seed files. I'm unfamiliar with Knex though, but I'm sure if you dig through the docs you can find how it uses the seed files to populate the database.